# Why doesn't my Evo bring up the Hacker's Keyboard?

Tags: htc-evo, input-methods

I have an HTC Evo, which is still on Froyo. I've installed Swype and Graffiti, and while I mostly use Graffiti (I used to rock a Palm III), I switch as I need.

I heard of the [Hacker's Keyboard](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard) on the Android Market and I jumped at it. I have ConnectBot on my phone and I sometimes use it to get a command line on both my home and work machine, and it seems like the right thing. But it isn't showing up as one of my choices. Just Swype, Touch Input and Graffiti.

I see "Gingerbread" in the description. Sprint hasn't pushed out Gingerbread yet. Is that the problem?

Comment: It says it only requires 2.2 so it seems like it should work. Did you remember to enable it in your settings?

Comment: I did not. And now I feel dumb. Nevermind.

Comment: Turn that into an answer so I can mark it solved.

Comment: Added. And I would say it's a common thing to overlook since you don't get prompted or anything, so I wouldn't feel dumb about it. Now someone else with a similar problem might land here and find a solution instead of tearing their hair out trying to debug it :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Newly installed third-party keyboards need to be enabled in your settings before they become selectable. Make sure you have it checked under `Settings->Language & Keyboard` after installing.